# App is not active. App is not accessible right now. Facebook Login issue in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, facebook, facebook-login, flutter-facebook-login

Facebook login not working with my flutter application. showing me this error after I press the login button from facebook page.

App not active: This app is not accessible right now and the app developer is aware of the issue. You will be able to log in when the app is reactivated.

I followed this steps: [Facebook developer account config steps](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android)
Used this pub package: [flutter_facebook_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth)

code:

```
 Future<void> signInWithFacebook() async {
try {
  // Trigger the sign-in flow
  final LoginResult loginResult = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

  // Create a credential from the access token
  final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
      FacebookAuthProvider.credential(loginResult.accessToken?.token ?? '');

  // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
  final UserCredential user = await FirebaseAuth.instance
      .signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);

  await loginWithThirdParty(user, AuthMethod.FACEBOOK);
} catch (ex) {
  showError(ex);
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.
[image: Facebook Login Error]